# Eris blockchain - Monax getting error while deploying smart contracts

Tags: blockchain, eris-blockchain

I am new to blockchain platforms and eris. trying to get a private blockchain up and running in my Mac OS from here
https://monax.io/docs/tutorials/getting-started/

all went fine until deployment of a smart contract. While performing "eris pkgs do" command, getting below error.

***Performing action. This can sometimes take a wee while
Error connecting to node (tcp://chain:46657) to get chain id: Post http://chain:46657: dial tcp 198.105.244.228:46657: getsockopt: connection refused
Could not perform pkg action service: Could not perform pkg action: Container interactive-73d789a8-4693-4a4c-bcf2-ae2005a12d23 exited with status 1***

update:
   I am now able to get past this error. Followed the Mona tutorial for docker machines.

This took me to the compiler error (error scenario 6 in getting started session).

Now getting below error. the IP address is taken from the active machine by issuing command "docker-machine ls".

GinguVjs-MacBook-Pro:idi ginguvj$ eris pkgs do --chain simplechain --address $addr --compiler 192.168.99.101:2376
Performing action. This can sometimes take a wee while
Executing Job                                 defaultAddr
Executing Job                                 setStorageBase
Executing Job                                 deployStorageK
failed to send HTTP request Post 192.168.99.101:2376: unsupported protocol scheme ""
Error compiling contracts: Compilers error:
Post 192.168.99.101:2376: unsupported protocol scheme ""

Could not perform pkg action service: Could not perform pkg action: Container interactive-671e81dc-4a1b-4e1e-b1ad-b51d955297b1 exited with status 1
GinguVjs-MacBook-Pro:idi ginguvj$

Comment: Going to need some context. What version of Eris are you using? Can you run a `eris --version` and include that version in your question.

Comment: hello, ran "eris version". Below is what I see. Eris CLI Version: 0.12.0

Comment: I am using Mac OS Sierra - 10.12.1.

Answer (score 0):

The compilation issue was resolved by adding a "-z" to the end.

"eris pkgs do --chain simplechain --address $addr -z"